# Get Number of "Business Seconds" Between Two Unix Timestamps

Tags: powerbi, dax

Given these two timestamps/converted to datetimes:

```
Start - 1668105400.814 - Thursday, November 10, 2022 12:36 PM
End   - 1668444427.195 - Monday, November 14, 2022 10:47 AM
```

...how can I get the number of seconds, adjusted for "business" days? With this example, you'll see that the start date was a Thursday (Friday was a holiday in Canada), and the end date was a Monday. Taking holidays into account isn't super important here, would be nice, but for simplicity of the solution, it would be cool to subtract 172800 seconds (2 days' worth) from the difference between the End and the Start if it stretches over a weekend.

My dataset looks like this:

```
type         created_at           emitted_at
assign       1668105400.814       1668105400.814
archive      1668105400.814       1668444427.195
```

How I'm currently calculating the number of seconds is in an added custom column with the formula:

```
_Created_To_Archive_Handle_Time = IF(Front_Email_Stats[type]="archive", ROUND((Front_Email_Stats[emitted_at] - Front_Email_Stats[conversation.created_at]), 1), BLANK())
```

...where it filters for type of `archive` only, and then subtracts the archived `emitted_at` timestamp from its `created_at` timestamp.

A naive approach would look something like this:

```
_Created_To_Archive_Handle_Time = IF(Front_Email_Stats[type]="archive", IF(AND(WEEKDAY(Front_Email_Stats[_created_at_datetime_custom_column]) < 7, WEEKDAY(Front_Email_Stats[_emitted_at_datetime_custom_column]) > 1), ROUND((Front_Email_Stats[emitted_at] - Front_Email_Stats[conversation.created_at]), 1) - 172800, ROUND((Front_Email_Stats[emitted_at] - Front_Email_Stats[conversation.created_at]), 1)), BLANK())
```

...where we filter for `archive` types only, and then do a simple check if the Start timestamp's day of week is less than Saturday (7 I think?) and the End timestamp's day of week is greater than Sunday (1?), but wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NETWORKDAYS() and then subtract the seconds manually.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/networkdays-dax